# I can't reproduce the function memoization from Functional Programming in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, runtime-error, std-call-once

The following code should be almost a copy of what the book *Functional Programming in C++* presents at the end of Chapter 6 section 1:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <mutex>

template<typename F>
class lazy_val {
  private:
    F m_computation;
    mutable decltype(m_computation()) m_cache;
    mutable std::once_flag m_value_flag;
  public:
    lazy_val(F f)
        : m_computation(f)
    {}
    operator const decltype(m_computation())& () const {
        std::call_once(m_value_flag, [this](){
            m_cache = m_computation();
        });
        return m_cache; // the execution never gets to this line
    }
};

int expensive() {
    std::cout << "expensive call...\n";
    return 7;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "non memoized" << '\n';
    std::cout << expensive() << '\n';
    std::cout << expensive() << '\n';
    std::cout << expensive() << '\n';
    const auto expensive_memo = lazy_val(expensive);
    std::cout << "memoized" << '\n';
    std::cout << expensive_memo << '\n'; // crash happens here
    std::cout << expensive_memo << '\n';
    std::cout << expensive_memo << '\n';
}
```

However, when I execute it (the compilation is goes fine), I get this error:

```
non memoized
expensive call...
7
expensive call...
7
expensive call...
7
memoized
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If ignore concurrency issues and only rely on a `mutable bool m_cache_initialized;` initialized to `false`, and a `if (!m_cache_initialized) { m_cache = m_computation(); m_cache_initialized = true; }`, then everything works.

This makes me think that the problem is with how I use `std::call_once`/`std::once_flag` in my code. However I don't see how it is different from what is shown in the book (constructor in Listing 6.2, but without the line initializing the `m_cache_initialized` to `false`, and the rest of the class is at the bottom of page 125 and top of 126).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using Linux and gcc. An "undocumented" feature of this implementation is that any C++ code that uses any thread-related stuff must be explicitly linked with `-lpthread`.

I reproduced your exact crash on Linux, after compiling (with `-std=c++17`) and linking without `-lpthread`. The shown code runs fine, if explicitly linked with `-lpthread`.

Comment: What the heck! Thanks, I could never find this out myself! :) I hope this will be useful to others. I'll some tags to make it easier to be found.